# How to mock observers easily in Objectbox in junit tests

Tags: android, junit, mocking, mockito, objectbox

Is there a simple way to mock observers in Objectbox? More specifically, I want my observer to be called when data is changed. Example:

```
private DataSubscription listen() {
    return addressBoxStore.query()
            .equal(Address_.address, address)
            .build()
            .subscribe()
            .on(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())
            .onError(this::handleError)
            .observer(observeAddress());
}

private DataObserver<List<Address>> observeAddress() {
    return addresses -> {
        // should only be one address
        if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
            // Run some code here
        }
    };
}
```

Given the above observer is registered, I want to add a junit test to make sure that my custom piece of code is called by Objectbox when data is changed. Is there a way to trigger events to occur in junit unit tests with some custom data so that I can verify some custom behaviour?

One approach is to mock the builder objects (example below), but that becomes ugly. Is there a better solution?

```
private void givenAddress(Answer answers) {
    when(subscriptionBuilder.observer(any(DataObserver.class))).then(answers);
    when(query.subscribe()).thenReturn(subscriptionBuilder);
    when(queryBuilder.build()).thenReturn(query);
    when(subscriptionBuilder.on(any())).thenReturn(subscriptionBuilder);
    when(subscriptionBuilder.onError(any())).thenReturn(subscriptionBuilder);
    when(queryBuilder.equal(any(Property.class), eq(ADDRESS))).thenReturn(queryBuilder);
    when(addressBox.query()).thenReturn(queryBuilder);

    underTest = new ClassToTest(addressBox);
}
```

This means that as soon as the observers are added, the data in the Answer is passed directly to it, but this solution is hard to read.

Comment: I dont think i got the whole point but using Mockitos `deep stubs` or `return self` behaviour may be a more pretty solution for mocking builders